# webpack set hash in publicPath cause error when include the chunkhash in filename?

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack

When webpack package the project, I need to upload the dist file to cdn, then improve the visit speed.

I need to keep the before bundle in cdn, so I use the build hash to unique the bundle.

But I found set `[hash]` in `publicPath` cause error when `chunkhash` in `filename` ?

I know remove the `chunkhash` in `filename` can resolve the question, but I still want to know why?

Here is my tiny webpack config:

```
const path = require("path");

module.exports = {
  entry: "./src/index.js",
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "./dist"),
    filename: "[chunkhash].js",
    publicPath: "https://my.cdn/[hash]/"
  }
};
```

The error info:

> ERROR in chunk main [entry]
>   [chunkhash].js
>   Cannot use [chunkhash] or [contenthash] for chunk in '[chunkhash].js' (use [hash] instead)

Answer (score 1):

You missunderstood the `publicPath` concept. Public path is where, from the root of the local domain that the files are, webpack has to request to get the necessary other chunks. For example, if it is `/`, webpack is going to request to `${CURRENT_DOMAIN}/dj834j9384j123.js`. So publicPath has to be sort of a path.

And also, if you are using webpack-dev-server or similar, chunkhash should not be used, only hash.

Comment: as doc says, can use `publicPath` to set cdn path. you can't explain if I change the `filename` to `[hash].js` no error.